# void** in API documentation

Tags: c++, c, pinvoke

I write an Interface in C# to a hardware device. I use PInvoke pattern to talk with the API. I found this in an API-Guide:

```
unsigned int ADQxxx_GetData( void* adq_cu_ptr, int adqxxx_num, void** target_buffers)
```

I never saw the void** data type. So what does it mean? I need a pointer to a pointer to get the data? Why they are using this concept? What are the advantages?

Thank you David and Mathew,

i found this notice:

Collects data from the device. Transfers data from the internal memory buffers in the ADQ device directly to the user-assigned buffers pointed to by target_buffers.One buffer for each channel of data.target_buffers can therefore be an array of pointers, depending on how many channels the capturing device has. This function is meant to be used together with the function MultiRecordSetup.

It seems like that when i record on two channels, i became an array with two pointer. So iam able to collect the data of both channels.

So may that is the solution.

Comment: Your question is more about `c` or `c++`  than `c#`,

Comment: Thx, i changed the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void**` is pointer to `void*`. Exactly what this means cannot be discerned from the prototype. You do need to read the documentation for the function.

For example, perhaps the parameter is used to let the function return a `void*` to the caller. It has to be done using a pointer in C because C uses pass by value exclusively. In your C# translation this would be `out IntPtr target_buffers`. The function would be translated like this:

```
static extern uint ADQxxx_GetData(IntPtr adq_cu_ptr, int adqxxx_num, 
    out IntPtr target_buffers);
```

Or perhaps the parameter is used to pass the function an array of pre-allocated buffers. In which case you would use `IntPtr[] target_buffers` and the translation would be:

```
static extern uint ADQxxx_GetData(IntPtr adq_cu_ptr, int adqxxx_num, 
    IntPtr[] target_buffers);
```

The bottom line is that you need to read the documentation for this function to make forward progress.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an array of pointers to void (but impossible to tell for sure without the documentation for the API call).

The equivalent in C# would be an array of objects (since you don't know what type is pointed to).

Unfortunately you won't be able to marshal the data without knowing the buffer type - but it is likely to be an array of IntPtr values that you have initialised to point to a block of memory returned by one of the methods in [`class Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).